# How to disable collapsing/expanding a CollapsingToolbarLayout on view scrolled?

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

By default, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is being collapsed or expanded when user scrolls the view from `NestedScrollView`.

How can I turn off auto expanding? What I want to achieve is a toolbar which I can expand or collapse only by calling `AppBarLayout::setExpanded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found an answer. In order to make toolbar collapsing on the screen scrolled, we have to create following layout hierarchy:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <Toolbar />
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <!-- content -->
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

In order to turn off this feature (to make scrolling not cause collapsing the toolbar), we have just to replace `NestedScrollView` with `ScrollView`.